# ¿Cómo validar si hay campos vacios dentro de una lista en Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, foreach

Tengo el siguiente método que regresa una lista, dentro de esa lista estan los campos de mi entidad, los cuales necesito validar que no regresen null o esten vacios, si ese es el caso debo de setearles el valor 0.00

pero como valido esos campos dentro de la lista? como seria con un foreach? y de que manera se hace en java 8?

```
    public ResponseEntity<?> consultar(String datenIni, String dateFin) throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
    List<ValuesDto> listVal = new ArrayList<ValuesDto>();
    try {
        listVal = consultRepository
                .consulValues(datenIni, dateFin);
        

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("An error ocurred looking for ValuesDto Data");
        response.put("success", false);
        response.put("error", e.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
    response.put("success", true);
    response.put("data", listVal);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

mi Entidad:

```
@Entity
    @Table
    public class ValuesDto implements Serializable {

    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "IDREGISTRO")
    private Integer idRegistro;

    
    
    @Column(name = "NOOPCIONES")
    private Double noOpciones;

    
    @Column(name = "FECHACOTIZACION")
    private Date fechaCotizacion;
    
    @Column(name = "NOREGISTROS")
    private String noRegistros;
    
    @Column(name = "NOPagos")
    private String noPagos;

    
    }
```

Comment: genera los getters y setters en tu entidad para de ese modo comprobar si el valor de la propiedad es null

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero para poder variar los valores de tu entidad necesitas crear los getters y setters, Una vez eso una manera facil de comprobar los valores de la lista puede ser usar un Iterator con un bucle y asi ya puedes comprobar si es null y darle un valor si asi quieres.

```
List<ValuesDto> listVal = new ArrayList<ValuesDto>();
Iterator<ValuesDto> iterator = listVal.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    ValuesDto aux = iterator.next();
    if(!aux.getNoOpciones())
        aux.setNoOpciones(0);
    //Asi con el resto de valores o como te sea mas comodo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Con esto recorrerías la lista chequeando por los valores que quieras.
Deberías agregarle los getters y setters en tu entity.

Para la comparación podes usar isBlank() que te va a devolver true si es null o vacío.

```
for (ValuesDto item : listVal) {
    if(StringUtils.isBlank(item.getNoRegistros()))
        item.setNoRegistros("0.00");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para validar los campos de tu entidad `ValuesDto` y asignarles un valor por defecto en caso de que sean `null` o estén vacíos, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera en Java 8:

```java
listVal.stream().forEach(valuesDto -> {
    if (valuesDto.getNoOpciones() == null) {
        valuesDto.setNoOpciones(0.00);
    }
    if (valuesDto.getNoRegistros() == null || valuesDto.getNoRegistros().isEmpty()) {
        valuesDto.setNoRegistros("0.00");
    }
    // Continúa con el resto de los campos...
});
```

Este código utiliza la función `forEach` de la interfaz `Stream` en Java 8 para iterar sobre cada elemento de `listVal`. Dentro del `forEach`, se comprueba si cada campo es `null` o está vacío, y si es así, se le asigna un valor por defecto.